# AWK: multi-step filtering of data based on the selected column

Tags: csv, awk

I am dealing with the post-processing of multi-column CSV arranged in fixed format: the first column corresponds to the line number (ID), the second one contains its population (POP,  the number of the samples fell into this ID) and the third column (dG) represent some inherent value of this ID (always negative):

```
ID, POP, dG
1, 7, -9.6000
2, 3, -8.7700
3, 6, -8.6200
4, 4, -8.2700
5, 6, -8.0800
6, 10, -8.0100
7, 9, -7.9700
8, 8, -7.8400
9, 16, -7.8100
10, 2, -7.7000
11, 1, -7.5600
12, 2, -7.5200
13, 9, -7.5100
14, 1, -7.5000
15, 2, -7.4200
16, 1, -7.3300
17, 1, -7.1700
18, 4, -7.1300
19, 3, -6.9200
20, 1, -6.9200
21, 2, -6.9100
22, 2, -6.8500
23, 10, -6.6900
24, 2, -6.6800
25, 1, -6.6600
26, 20, -6.6500
27, 1, -6.6500
28, 5, -6.5700
29, 3, -6.5500
30, 2, -6.4600
31, 2, -6.4500
32, 1, -6.3000
33, 7, -6.2900
34, 1, -6.2100
35, 1, -6.2000
36, 3, -6.1800
37, 1, -6.1700
38, 4, -6.1300
39, 1, -6.1000
40, 2, -6.0600
41, 3, -6.0600
42, 8, -6.0200
43, 2, -6.0100
44, 1, -6.0100
45, 1, -5.9800
46, 2, -5.9700
47, 1, -5.9300
48, 6, -5.8800
49, 4, -5.8300
50, 4, -5.8000
51, 2, -5.7800
52, 3, -5.7200
53, 1, -5.6600
54, 1, -5.6500
55, 4, -5.6400
56, 2, -5.6300
57, 1, -5.5700
58, 1, -5.5600
59, 1, -5.5200
60, 1, -5.5000
61, 3, -5.4200
62, 4, -5.3600
63, 1, -5.3100
64, 5, -5.2500
65, 5, -5.1600
66, 1, -5.1100
67, 1, -5.0300
68, 1, -4.9700
69, 1, -4.7700
70, 2, -4.6600
```

In order to reduce the number of the lines I filtered this CSV with the aim to search for the line with the highest number in the second column (POP), using the following AWK expression:

```
# search CSV for the line with the highest POP and save all linnes before it, while keeping minimal number of the linnes (3) in the case if this line is found at the begining of CSV.
awk -v min_lines=3 -F ", " 'a < $2 {for(idx=0; idx < i; idx++) {print arr[idx]} print $0; a=int($2); i=0; printed=NR} a > $2 && NR > 1 {arr[i]=$0; i++}END{if(printed <= min_lines) {for(idx = 0; idx <= min_lines - printed; idx++){print arr[idx]}}}' input.csv > output.csv
```

For simple case when the string with maximum POP is located on the first line, the script will save this line (POP max) +2 lines after it(=min_lines=3).

For more complicated case, if the line with POP max is located in the middle of the CSV, the script detect this line + all the precedent lines from the begining of the CSV and list them in the new CSV keeping the original order. However, in that case output.csv would contain too many lines since the search string (with highest POP) is located on 26th line:

```
ID, POP, dG
1, 7, -9.6000
2, 3, -8.7700
3, 6, -8.6200
4, 4, -8.2700
5, 6, -8.0800
6, 10, -8.0100
7, 9, -7.9700
8, 8, -7.8400
9, 16, -7.8100
10, 2, -7.7000
11, 1, -7.5600
12, 2, -7.5200
13, 9, -7.5100
14, 1, -7.5000
15, 2, -7.4200
16, 1, -7.3300
17, 1, -7.1700
18, 4, -7.1300
19, 3, -6.9200
20, 1, -6.9200
21, 2, -6.9100
22, 2, -6.8500
23, 10, -6.6900
24, 2, -6.6800
25, 1, -6.6600
26, 20, -6.6500
```

In order to reduce the total number of the lines up to 3-5 lines in the output CSV, how it would be possible to customize my filter in order to save only the lines with a minor difference (e.g. the values in the pop column should match (POP >0.5 max(POP)) ), while comparing each line with the line having bigest value in the POP column? Finally, I need always to keep the first line as well as the line with the maximal value in the output. So the AWK solution should filter multi-string CSV in the following manner (please ignore coments in #):

```
ID, POP, dG 
1, 7, -9.6000    
9, 16, -7.8100
26, 20, -6.6500 # this is POP max detected over all lines
```

Comment: But why is `6, 10, -8.0100` not in input since `10` is exact 50% of `20`?

Comment: Thank you for the correction!  Indeed,I mean that I need to keep in the output the lines where pop D is close to pop MAX (POP >0.5 max(POP)),so it does not fit the lines with POP= 10 but definetely takes the line 9 (with POP=16), as it shown in the expected output.

Comment: Please reduce your example to a [mcve]. Any sample input/output with a scroll bar isn't minimal and so wastes our time trying to understand it all. You could probably demonstrate whatever problem you're asking for help with using 10 lines of input instead of 70.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This 2 phase `awk` should work for you:

```sh
awk -F ', ' -v n=2 'NR == 1 {next}
FNR==NR { if (max < $2) {max=$2; if (FNR==n) n++} next}
FNR <= n || $2 > (.5 * max)' file file

ID, POP, dG
1, 7, -9.6000
9, 16, -7.8100
26, 20, -6.6500
```

Comment: it works well! but there is a bug when the line with POP max is the first line (which always should be taken in output regardgless of the value) it takes some lines with the POP much lower than 50%

Comment: yes, this works! sorry one more precise- in the case if pop(max)  in found on the first line, will it be possible to keep the first two lines in the output instead of the first line like it does now ? :-)

Comment: like this it always takes the first two lines regardless of the position of the popMAX while I would do it only in the case if popMAX is found on the first line (and so just taking the first two lines ignoring POP column in that case) ...

Comment: Sorry but that's why adding requirements in comments is discouraged. Please update question with sample input and expected output for this and then I can modify answer accordingly.

Comment: No problems, actually the present version also is very cool so I accept like it goes! Thank you again. Cheers